# Изменить размера заполненного массива C# в C++

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

Мне необходимо в C# создать массив типа `double` с фиксированной величиной. Далее я его заполняю значениями. Передаю массив в библиотеку C++ и там часть данных отсекаю. После я должен вернуть обратно данный массив, но уже с другим размером. Как это можно реализовать?
Без усечения версия

C#

```
int count = 5;
float[] resultVertices = new float[count];
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(resultVertices, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr address = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
myFunc(address, count);
handle.Free()
```

C++

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void MyCppFunc2(float* resultVerts, int vertLength)
{
resultVerts[0] = 0.123f;
}
```

Comment: Зачем ему менять размер в принципе? Забейте нулями те данные которые вам не нужны, а при выборке в С# перебирайте по условию.. например.. Или делать двойную ссылку, и там ресайзить, но это явно лишнее, я понимаю ещё добавить, но отрезать.. смысла нет.. Кроме головной боли это ничего не принесёт.

Comment: @NewView тоже верно, не подумал про это, спасибо)